# Code is working fine in firefox but not working in chrome. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest

In my web application I've the following code in a function. And when I execute the code in firefox it works fine and gives me the output. But when I execute the same code in chrome the function is entering infinite loop and returning (its not throwing any exception or error).

***And the Info:* `elem` is an xml element not html element; and that xml is a SVG image**

The Code is like this:

**Function call:**

```
buildElemView(viewElement, container, 1, viewType);
```

**and then the function:**

```
function buildElemView(elem, container, start, viewType){

        var vwType = viewType;

        var cat = $(elem).find('cat:first').text();
                //alert("cat is "+cat);
        var type = $(elem).find('type:first').text();
        var id = $(elem).find('eid:first').text();
        var mid = $(elem).find('mid:first').text();

        var parentMids = $(elem).parents().map(function () {
              return $(this).find('mid:first').text();
            })
        .get().reverse().join("");

        if (viewType==1 && Number(eleCat>60) && Number(cat)<40)    
            return;

        var parentElementId = parentMids;
        var elementGroupId = parentMids+mid;

        var grp = $(elem).find('gr:first').text();

        var cz = $(elem).find('cz:first').text();

        var zo = $(elem).find('zo:first').text();
        var yo = $(elem).find('yo:first').text();


        var rotate = ($(elem).find('rt:first').text().split(';'))[0];
        var scale = ($(elem).find('sc:first').text().split(';'))[0];
        var positionx = ($(elem).find('px:first').text().split(';'))[0];
        var positiony = ($(elem).find('py:first').text().split(';'))[0];
        var positionz = ($(elem).find('pz:first').text().split(';'))[0];
        var dimension = $(elem).find('dm:first').text();
        var parentdimension = $(elem).parent().find('dm:first').text();
        var parentheight=0;
        if (parentdimension !='')
            parentheight = (parentdimension.split(';'))[2];
        if (parentheight==undefined || parentheight=="null")
            parentheight =0;

        var height = 0;
        if (dimension !='')
            height = (dimension.split(';'))[2];
        if (height==undefined || height=="null")
            height =0;


        var transformStr = "";

        var num =0;
        if (start && start==1)
        {
            transformStr= "translate(0,0) rotate(0) scale(1,1)";
            if (viewType==1 && Number(eleCat)<100) {
                var px = 0;
                var py = 0;
                if (scaleX==-1) px = 15000;
                if (scaleY==-1) py = 15000;

                transformStr = "translate("+ px+","+py +") rotate(0) scale("+ scaleX+","+scaleY+ ")";
            }

            if (Number(type)==50 || Number(type)==80 || Number(type)==100)
                vwType=4;
        }
        else {
            if (viewType<3 || Number(cat)>40)
                {
                   if (viewType==2) {

                       var px = positionx;
                       var py = positiony;
                       var pz = positionz;

                        if (parentheight)
                            positiony = Number(parentheight)-Number(positionz)-Number(height);

}


//And there is a lot of Code here but its not even executing the entire code //strightly coming to alert box after clicking debug stepover.

}
```

The Function is too big I can give you this much only...

But by debugging the problem happens here...

```
var cat = $(elem).find('cat:first').text();
var type = $(elem).find('type:first').text();
var id = $(elem).find('eid:first').text();
var mid = $(elem).find('mid:first').text();
```

I came to a conclusion after putting an alert message in between them like this.

```
var cat = $(elem).find('cat:first').text();
var type = $(elem).find('type:first').text();
alert("Alert");
var id = $(elem).find('eid:first').text();
var mid = $(elem).find('mid:first').text();
```

In firefox alert is shown once and all the lines are executed and returned. But in chrome alert is keep on coming. It's not executing first two lines and last two lines just executing alert and that too continuously doing it.

**Info:** This worked fine with chrome version 47 but now not working in version 49 after updation.

Please do help why this weird behavior of Chrome.

Comment: Can you show us the whole function and how you call it?

Comment: I suppose there are no errors in the Chrome console? Have you tried disabling all Chrome extensions?

Comment: @Technoh Yep there are no errors thrown but its not executing the svg XML...

Comment: And have you tried without any Chrome extension?

Comment: @Technoh still not working... When I researched the same topic Chrome is having issues with SVG rendering... Do you have any idea..

Comment: Not specifically for Chrome, no. My only thought is that you could try to post on Chrome's developer forum.

Comment: @Technoh Please share the link...

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/chrome

Answer (score 0):

I had a related issue a monte ago, and i solved it writing the definition of the function after the call

Comment: baabu Its not the issue of function call... Its the issue of SVG rendering in chrome